# Handle both GPRS and WiFi connections at the same time in Android as in desktop Windows

Tags: android, wifi, gprs

Before my actual question. I want to tell that we used to handle both GPRS and WiFi connections at the same time in windows. We even used to change priority of GPRS/WiFi connection by settings its priority in OS routing table. We did all this in C#.

Now I want to handle both GPRS and WiFi at the same time in android and then allow user to connect to either one or another or both at the sametime.

As per my search, all the searches say that it can't be done on android. If wifi is active then it will be given highest priority and GPRS will be inactive as soon as wifi is inactive then GPRS is active [OS does this].

Please give me suggestions and solutions. I need it very urgent.

Regards,

Syed Mustehsan Ikram

Comment: I've done a lot of apps that require GPRS for mobile identification, I've always just had a button that turned the wifi off. Why exactly do you want an app that uses both at the same time?

Comment: Yes an application that will use both at the same time? And at the same time if i have multiple Wifi networks, Can i switch among them as well?

Comment: No. My application always used one or the other. I'm not sure if you can change the current wifi network. My real question is why do you want to do any of this?

Comment: My application is kind of emergency related application and it needs to send real time data. That application can either in hospital or in field so it needs to send data fast. so i need to send data via the fastest network. Data can be small or large.

Comment: Can any body help or give any work around or any other better solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, it is not possible to use more than one networks simultaneously.